# how to display text in Weekly number column of Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar script, my requirement is display the text with button link in the weekly number column.

[image: full calendar week number]

Comment: For that you'd have to alter the source code of the view, I think. There's no way to do this through the documented API.

Comment: I think so, anyway thanks..

Answer (score 0):

with out modifying the source code, i could acheive this adding a function for weekNumberCalculation.

```
weekNumbers: true,
            weekNumbersWithinDays: false,
            weekNumberCalculation: function(weekMoment){

                return "Week " + weekMoment.isoWeek();
            },
```

With this code, instead of 44 it start showing week 44.